# Directly redirect without www

Tags: apache, redirect

i have apache server and i have a trouble.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF5t0.png

Now, when i enter to my site http://example.net, it redirects to https://www then to https

I want

```
http -> https://
http:/www -> https://
https://www -> https://
```

It's important that it was directly

Answer (score 0):

First rule get all non https and second rule get all www to https://example.net/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```